# Why are red & black stranded wires connected to neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I found an inaccessible box in the attic, so I opened it to disconnect the wires so I could move the box to an accessible location. Here's what I found in the box:

• Two normal sets of NM wire, black to black, white to white, bare to bare.

• A pair of red and black stranded (not solid) wires, and no other wires, coming into the box through flexible metal conduit, even though it was run above a ceiling and didn't have to be in conduit. This red and black wires are connected to the WHITE wires from the normal NM sets. FWIW, the red and black insulation is in poor condition and a bit crumbly.

None of the wires in any of the 3 sets are hot, though I did disconnect some wires elsewhere in the house as part of the remodel, so maybe these are downstream from what I disconnected.

I can't trace the wires without doing a lot of demo work.

[image: How the wires are connected in the box]

[image: Photo of black + red wires, which were connected to neutral]

Comment: Sooooo .... you followed the flex metal conduit and it lead to ... ?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to follow that mystery flex conduit to wherever it leads.  It looks like an inappropriately switched neutral from here, but it could be someone got their colors backwards and the switch is in the hot instead

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put that in the question but forgot:  I can't easily trace the wires without doing a lot of demo work.  The conduit runs between a ceiling below and a finished floor above, and I'm not eager to tear up a ceiling or a floor.  I'll try to find my inspection camera tomorrow, but I'm not sure how far I'll be able to trace it that way..

Comment: They have electronic wire tracer kits.  (Google them).

Comment: If you can't follow it, the other option is to work out what no longer works...

Comment: Both red and black wires were connected to the two whites? Four wires on that wire nut: white 1, white 2, black, red?

Comment: Start opening boxes to see if any of them have FMC with a black & red (but no white) running into them. That's probably the easiest way to determine where it goes without demolition or purchasing other tools.

Comment: Could be a bootleg neutral.   in which case leaving it disconnected will make matters worse. look inside the drier outlet.

Answer (score 2):

> it was run above a ceiling and didn't have to be in conduit

It does have to be in conduit.  NEC 300.3 strictly forbids installing wires willy nilly above the ceiling.  The red and black wires would be illegal without the FMC.

> inaccessible box in the attic

If you can access it, this is allowable.  NEC distinguishes accessible from "readily accessible" which only applies to things like disconnects and interruptors.

For now, the safest thing to do is replace the box, reattach the FMC, and cap off the 2 wires.  If your project involves other electrical work, I recommend starting a set of diagrams for reach room or circuit to aid in tracing things that can't be exposed through demolition.

Comment: The red and black appear to be BX cable...does BX need to be in conduit?

Comment: @Huesmann AC type cables, including BX brand, do not require conduit.  This photo is not really clear enough for me to see which type, but the 'conduit' in the question appears to be the metal coil.

Comment: Robert Chapin, I don't see anything in NEC 300.3 that prescribes conduit above ceilings.  I also don't see it in 300.4, which is where I'd expect to see it if it exists.  Can you quote the language you're referring to?

Comment: @MichaelBluejay "shall only be installed where part of a recognized wiring method."  You won't find any recognized wiring method since K&T that allows single wires to roam freely through a dwelling.  There are several methods, so it doesn't have to be exactly FMC or AC or NM or EMT, but there's absolutely no legal way those single wires can run through attic unprotected.

Comment: @Robert Chapin.  Okay, I think you meant that individual conductors have to be protected, since NM wire certainly doesn't.  I was unfamiliar with BX wire, I thought the metal I was seeing was conduit, now I realize that's it's a metal + wire combo, and serves to protect the wires so they're not installed as individual conductors without a jacket.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's FMC not BX due to the coating on the wires and the lack of a paper packing peeking out...